# JavaScript not getting called

Tags: javascript, html

I have below JavaScript Code. It not getting called when page is loaded. 
Even Alert is not displaying;
**moment.min.js** is placed in same folder..

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="moment.min.js">
alert("Testing Hello...")
var mysql_date = '2013-01-25 10:00:00';
var date = moment(mysql_date , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'); // new moment.js object.

// To display the date in a different format use:
var date_format1 = date.format('MMM, Do'); // Format here would be Jan, 25th
var date_format2 = date.format('MMMM, Do, YYYY'); // January, 25th, 2013
alert(date_format1);
alert(date_format2);
console.log(date_format1, date_format2);
</script>
```

Please let me know why this script is not loaded when page is loaded

Comment: There is probably something else on your page throwing a JavaScript error.  There are no errors in your console?  Also, it's a good idea to always use semicolons, even if they aren't technically needed.  It's also generally a good idea to not use a `src` on a script tag, as well as including code within.  It works, but it is debatable whether or not it will continue to work in the future.

Comment: No it does not work. Whatever is inside the script tag with a src is ignored, hence Logan's problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

either content or src

try this

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="moment.min.js">
</script>

<script>
alert("Testing Hello...")
var mysql_date = '2013-01-25 10:00:00';
var date = moment(mysql_date , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'); // new moment.js object.

// To display the date in a different format use:
var date_format1 = date.format('MMM, Do'); // Format here would be Jan, 25th
var date_format2 = date.format('MMMM, Do, YYYY'); // January, 25th, 2013
alert(date_format1);
alert(date_format2);
console.log(date_format1, date_format2);
</script>
```

Comment: missing ; in first alert i.e `alert("Testing Hello...");`

Answer (score 3):

For the calling the JavaScript on page and include the JavaScript file below is solution

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="moment.min.js"> </script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
window.onload=function() {
  alert("Testing Hello...")
  var mysql_date = '2013-01-25 10:00:00';
  var date = moment(mysql_date , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'); // new moment.js object.

  // To display the date in a different format use:
  var date_format1 = date.format('MMM, Do'); // Format here would be Jan, 25th
  var date_format2 = date.format('MMMM, Do, YYYY'); // January, 25th, 2013
  alert(date_format1);
  alert(date_format2);
  console.log(date_format1, date_format2);
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why include `src` attribute when your are including javascript directly?

Add the code in `moment.min.js` and just write `<script src="moment.min.js"></script>`

**OR**

```
<script src='moment.min.js'></script>
<script>
alert("Testing Hello...")
var mysql_date = '2013-01-25 10:00:00';
var date = moment(mysql_date , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'); // new moment.js object.

// To display the date in a different format use:
var date_format1 = date.format('MMM, Do'); // Format here would be Jan, 25th
var date_format2 = date.format('MMMM, Do, YYYY'); // January, 25th, 2013
alert(date_format1);
alert(date_format2);
console.log(date_format1, date_format2);
</script>
```